# Getting error while importing linear regression library

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import
CountVectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')

```
TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-16-73d0626d2ad3> in <module>()

----> 1 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

2 vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english') #Creating the object for count vectorizer and removing the stop words.

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in <module>()

     20 from scipy.sparse import issparse
     21 

---> 22 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32

     23 from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight

     24 from . import _joblib

__init__.pxd in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash()

TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes
```

Comment: What version do you have installed? It works for me under version 0.24.2.

Comment: @F.Strothmann even if i try to run import sklearn sklearn.__version__
Facing the same issue.

Comment: Show the complete stack trace.

Comment: Please put that *in your question*. Use the Edit button bottom left next to Share. It's impossible to read in a comment.